# Successful cross country skiers switching to Biathlon

Tags: biathlon, cross-country-skiing

Why is it that a number of really successful cross-country skiers (especially sprinters) switch to Biathlon after a few years on the cross-country circuit?
Thinking of Stinna Nilsson and Anamarija Lampic and even Denise Hermann who won an Olympic medal in cross-country before switching to Biathlon